# Referencing previous group possible within the same regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to perform a regex in Python. I want to match on a file path that does not have a domain extension and additionally, I only want to get those file paths that have 20 characters max after the last '\' of the file path. For example, given the data:

```
c:\users\docs\cmd.exe
c:\users\docs\files\ewyrkfdisadfasdfaffsfdasfsafsdf
c:\users\docs\files\target
```

I would want to match on 'target', and not the other two lines. It should be noted that in my current situation, **using the re module or python operations is not an option, as this regex is fed into the program (which uses re.match() ), so I have do to this within a regex string.**

I have two regexes:

```
^([^.]+)$ will match the the last 2 lines

([^\\]{,20}$) will match 'cmd.exe' and 'target'
```

How can I combine these two into one regex? I tried backreferencing (?P=, etc), but couldn't get it to work. Is this even possible?

Comment: Is something like `^(.*\\)+[^\.]{0,20}$` what you want? According to https://regex101.com/ this works…

Comment: Hmm that seems to get the right line, but not it gets the whole line, not just 'target'

Comment: Ouh, that’s a bit more difficult… you would potentially need to trust “lookbehinds”… do you really want to go that far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `\\([^\\.]{1,20})(?:$|\n)`? It seems to work for me.

- `\\` is escaped literal backslash.
- `(` start of capture group.
- `[^\\.]` match anything except literal backslash or literal dot character
- `{1,20}` match class 1-20 times, as many times as possible (greedy).
- `)` end the capture group.
- `(?:` starts a non-capturing group
- `$` match the end of the string.
- `|` is the 'or' operator for this group
- `\n` matches a line-feed or newline character (ASCII 10)
- `)` end of non-capturing group

To create this, I used https://regex101.com/#python which is a very good resource in my opinion because it explains every part of the regex and neatly shows the captured groups in real time.

Comment: this worked for me... how did you do this? Mind walking me through it?

Comment: Actually this is the more clever one… it selects up to 20 characters at the end (`$`) that are not `.` or `\ ` (`[^\\.]`). But shouldn’t it be `[^\\\.]` then?

Comment: @Xufox I think you can do it both ways. Within a character class, `.` gets interpreted literally and you don't need to escape it.

Comment: I am confused on how you are matching the last backslash. '\\' will match the first backslash right?

Comment: @jeffrey It will try to match the first one but it will fail, so it will try the next one (if it exists) and so on. I'm matching the last backslash by enforcing the rule that the backslash must be followed by 1-20 non-backslash non-dot characters and then the string should end.

Comment: Interestingly, If I move the target line to the middle and the previous middle line to the end, the match seems to fail. Can anyone verify this?

Comment: @jeffrey It will fail because `$` only matches the end of the full string, not a new line character `\n`. I have updated my answer though and now the regex uses a non-capturing group to match end of string or newline character.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = r"""c:\users\docs\cmd.exe
... c:\users\docs\files\ewyrkfdisadfasdfaffsfdasfsafsdf
... c:\users\docs\files\target""".split('\n')
>>> [re.match(r'.*\\([^.]{,20})$', x) for x in s]
[None, None, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f6ad9631558>]
```

also

```
>>> [re.findall(r'.*\\([^.]{,20})$', x) for x in s]
[[], [], ['target']]
```

This means:

`.*\\` - grab everything up to and including the last `\`
`([^.]{,20})` - make sure there are no `.` in the remaining upto 20 characters
`$` - end of line

The `()` around the middle group indicate that it should be the group returned as the match

Comment: This grabs the line 'c:\\users\\docs\\files\\target', but I'm looking for 'target'

Comment: @jeffrey, easy to fix. I just misunderstood